# raspberry piのvmlinux.hを作成したい。

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel

## やりたいこと

以下の記事を真似して、raspberry pi用のvmlinux.hを作成したいです。

[異なるカーネルのvmlinux.hを生成するには | libbpfとclangでポータブルなBPF CO-REバイナリ作成](https://gihyo.jp/admin/serial/01/ubuntu-recipe/0694#sec2_h3)

## やったこと

ダウンロードするファイルのリンクを、ラズパイ用に変更して同じようにしました。

```
wget http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux-raspi/linux-image-5.15.0-1038-raspi-dbgsym_5.15.0-1038.41_arm64.ddeb

dpkg-deb -x linux-image-5.15.0-1038-raspi-dbgsym_5.15.0-1038.41_arm64.ddeb .

bpftool btf dump file usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi format c > vmlinux.h
Error: failed to load BTF from usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi: No such file or directory
```

pathは存在しています。

[image: treeで確認した、ディレクトリ構成]

## 躓いていること

vmlinux.hを作成する方法は、

1. 上記のやり方
2. .configのCONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTFをyにして、/sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux を作成する。
   2のやり方は、そもそも.configに項目がないので、できなさそうだと判断しました。

なので、今回は上記の方法でraspberry piのvmlinux.hを作成する方法　もしくは、　別の方法でraspberry piのvmlinux.hを作成する方法を教えてください。

Comment: "No such file or directory" のエラーが出ているので、指定したパスが正しいものなのかをまず確認すべきです。

Comment: 指定したパスはあっているようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

同じ様に試してみましたが、そもそも `vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi` には `.BTF` セクションが存在しません。なので、「1. 上記のやり方」は無効です。

```bash
$ wget http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux-raspi/linux-image-5.15.0-1038-raspi-dbgsym_5.15.0-1038.41_arm64.ddeb
$ dpkg-deb -x linux-image-5.15.0-1038-raspi-dbgsym_5.15.0-1038.41_arm64.ddeb .
$ bpftool btf dump file usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi format c > vmlinux.h
libbpf: failed to find '.BTF' ELF section in usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi
Error: failed to load BTF from usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi: No data available

$ readelf -S usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi
There are 42 section headers, starting at offset 0x14de8138:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .head.text        PROGBITS         ffff800008000000  00010000
       0000000000010000  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     65536
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS         ffff800008010000  00020000
       0000000000ded078  0000000000000008  AX       0     0     65536
  [ 3] .got.plt          PROGBITS         ffff800008dfd078  00e0d078
       0000000000000018  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [ 4] .rodata           PROGBITS         ffff800008e00000  00e10000
       00000000004ab81f  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4096

                        :

$ readelf -S usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi | grep -i btf
$ echo $?
1

$ objdump -s -j .BTF usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi

usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi:     file format elf64-little

objdump: section '.BTF' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
```

> 別の方法でraspberry piのvmlinux.hを作成する方法

[pahole/pahole.git - Pahole and other DWARF utils](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/devel/pahole/pahole.git) を使います。(`DWARF` の debug data から `BTF` を生成)

```bash
$ pahole --compile usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.15.0-1038-raspi > vmlinux.h
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。　無事vmlinux.h作成できました！！

Answer (score 0):

ファイルが見つからない、とおっしゃってますので、ファイル指定が間違ってます。

> 指定したパスはあっているようです。

それが間違ってます。
コードの提示がないので、言えるのはここまでですね